# NSData with CCCrypt in multi-threaded environment

Tags: objective-c, aes, nsdata

I have a file that was encrypted using AES.
I use the following NSData category:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@implementation NSData (AES)

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {

    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;

    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer,       bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    NSLog(@"Bytes decrypted: %d",numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    NSLog(@"Decrypt failed with error code %d",cryptStatus);
    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

@end
```

The descrypt process seems to work fine when I load the entire file from filesystem with the following code:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
```

The problem occurs when the file is not read with the previous call but when an external code that chunk the file and init an NSData with only a little chunk of data and try to decrypt this, in particolar the problems occurs when different thread use this code (or at least is what i think):

```
- (NSData *)readDataOfLength:(NSUInteger)length
{
    HTTPLogTrace2(@"%@[%p]: readDataOfLength:%lu", THIS_FILE, self, (unsigned long)length);

    if (![self openFileIfNeeded])
    {
        // File opening failed,
        // or response has been aborted due to another error.
        return nil;
    }

    // Determine how much data we should read.
    // 
    // It is OK if we ask to read more bytes than exist in the file.
    // It is NOT OK to over-allocate the buffer.

    UInt64 bytesLeftInFile = fileLength - fileOffset;

    NSUInteger bytesToRead = (NSUInteger)MIN(length, bytesLeftInFile);

    // Make sure buffer is big enough for read request.
    // Do not over-allocate.

    if (buffer == NULL || bufferSize < bytesToRead)
    {
        bufferSize = bytesToRead;
        buffer = reallocf(buffer, (size_t)bufferSize);

        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            HTTPLogError(@"%@[%p]: Unable to allocate buffer", THIS_FILE, self);

            [self abort];
            return nil;
        }
    }

    // Perform the read

    HTTPLogVerbose(@"%@[%p]: Attempting to read %lu bytes from file", THIS_FILE, self, bytesToRead);

    ssize_t result = read(fileFD, buffer, bytesToRead);

    // Check the results

    if (result < 0)
    {
        HTTPLogError(@"%@: Error(%i) reading file(%@)", THIS_FILE, errno, filePath);

        [self abort];
        return nil;
    }
    else if (result == 0)
    {
        HTTPLogError(@"%@: Read EOF on file(%@)", THIS_FILE, filePath);

        [self abort];
        return nil;
    }
    else // (result > 0)
    {
        HTTPLogVerbose(@"%@[%p]: Read %d bytes from file", THIS_FILE, self, result);

        fileOffset += result;

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:result];
        return [data AES256DecryptWithKey:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456"];
        //return data;
    }
}
```

What happens is that the function CCCrypt in this case fail with error code -4304 AKA "kCCDecodeError - Input data did not decode or decrypt properly."

Moreover if in the CCCrypt call instead of kCCOptionPKCS7Padding i pass 0 -> No padding the method decrypt the first chunk of data but when the thread is switched it fails with -4300 AKA "kCCParamError - Illegal parameter value."

With the following message in console:

```
[Switching to process 13059 thread 0x0]
2011-05-25 18:00:03.631 Drm[1843:6e0b] Bytes decrypted: 131072
2011-05-25 18:00:03.647 Drm[1843:6e0b] Bytes decrypted: 68096
[Switching to process 11779 thread 0x0]
2011-05-25 18:00:04.547 Drm[1843:6e0b] Bytes decrypted: 0
2011-05-25 18:00:04.555 Drm[1843:6e0b] Decrypt failed with error code -4300
```

Someone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AES is a block cipher. You must decrypt it one block at a time. An AES block is 128-bits (this is not related to the "256" in `AES256DecryptWithKey`). So you must ensure that the data you pass is a multiple of 16 bytes.

I haven't tried to use `CCCrypt()` this way, that's not really what it's for. `CCCrypt()` is a convenience function when you want to do a one-shot decryption. When you want to do "as you go" decryption, you use `CCCryptorCreate()` and then multiple calls to `CCCryptorUpdate()` and finally `CCCryptorFinal()` (or you can call `CCCryptorFinal()` and then `CCCryptorReset()` to decrypt more stuff with the same key). Finally you call `CCCryptorRelease()` to release your cryptor.

**EDIT** I was thinking about this some more, and realized that `CCCrypt()` can't be used this way even if you broke up the input into 16-byte chunks. Each block of AES encryption modifies the IV of the next block, so you can't just start someone in the middle of a stream. That's why you need a persistent `CCCryptor` object over the entire session.

Comment: So your suggestion is to have a shared reference of CCCryptor and use it between multiple CCCryptorUpdate() call ? I will definitely give it a try and i will let you know! 
But the kCCOptionPKCS7Padding option isn't used to not care about the padding?

Comment: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding indicates that it should apply PKCS padding to what you hand it. You're handing it the middle of a stream. You can't just apply padding randomly in the middle of a stream. (You also need to keep track of your IV, so you can't just start decrypting in the middle of the stream either.)

Comment: I tried to implement what you suggested me, but there are still problems: the class that calls my code and therefore requires the chunk of data (and of which I have no control) sometimes requires the chunk of data that are not multiples of 16 bytes rather generally required is 2 bytes and this break my decrypt process

Comment: You can encrypt 2-bytes of data. It'll be padded using the padding algorithm you request (PKCS7 in your example) to 16-bytes and encrypted. The resulting crypttext will always be a multiple of 16-bytes. If you have 2 bytes of crypttext, it's not AES, or you threw away part of the packet.

Comment: My problem isn't in ecnryption process but in decryption. The system that try to read from my code ask me for 2byte chunk but i can't decrypt 2byte.

Comment: Correct. There is no such thing as a 2-byte block of AES. This isn't a coding problem; it's a violation of the algorithm. Where are you getting the encrypted data from?